# Reading valued from properties file at Runtime

Tags: spring, properties

I want to get specific value based on request from the property file.how to do that?

I have following spring configuration.i want to set the value for Exprops as per the request and get corresponding values from the properties file

```
<bean id="Prop" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:ErrorMessage.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="PropertiesBean" class="com.util.PropertiesUtil">
    <property name="Exprops" value="${EXampleExceptiion}"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is only to configure your application, somehow static, it is not intended to be invoked by you application.

Comment: I guess you'll have to implement this yourself. There's no specific support from Spring for that as far as I know.

Comment: thanks @Ralph,@Benjamin..can any one provide me implementation where file  read from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer can be use to set the value at runtime

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [PropertiesFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html) to inject the [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html?is-external=true) in a Bean.

```
<bean id="myPropertiesBean"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:ErrorMessage.properties"/>
</bean>
```

This provides a [Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html?is-external=true) Object/Bean which can be injected under the name `myPropertiesBean` in any Bean (`<property name="x" ref="myPropertiesBean"/>`).

In addition Spring provides the util namespace (since Spring 2.5):
There you can write the PropertyFactoryBean definition a bit shorter:

```
<util:properties id="myPropertiesBean"
 location="classpath:ErrorMessage.properties"/>
```

@see [Spring Reference Chapter C.2.2.3.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties)

Comment: Thanks@Ralph,This look better

Comment: Can we write multiple properties in the same PropertiesFactoryBean which will be used by different Spring beans

Comment: @Vish: PropertiesFactoryBean provides java.util.Properties - which are multiple properties! (or did you mean, multiple propertie files). And yes, you can use them in different beans (each will get its one instance of java.util.Properties, but with the same key/values)

Comment: Autowiring this doesn't resolve values if your values are other variables.

Answer (score 1):

All use the following for doing this programmatically

```
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("beans.xml"));
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer cfg = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
cfg.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("jdbc.properties"));
cfg.postProcessBeanFactory(factory);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<util:properties id="" location="location of prop file" />
```

this return java.util.Properties object