# How to integrate Jasypt with a Spring 4 app with Java configuration?

Tags: java, spring, encryption, jasypt

I want to add properties files encryption with Jasypt in my Spring 4 app (without Spring Boot). The configuration is in Java.

I found solution for Spring 3.1 XML config, and for Spring Boot but not Spring4 Java config.

I tried declaring it as suggested in the doc for 3.1 (http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html) in a Java config way, but it doesn't load the properties.

```
@Bean
public EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(new OurCustomEncryptor());
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(
            new ClassPathResource("config-encrypted.properties")
    );
    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem was twofold :

First, I had another `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` declared somewhere else in the config which seemed to override this one.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

So getting rid of it allowed me to go further.

Secondly, it worked for properties injected with `@Value` annotation but not when trying to retrieve the value through Spring `Environment#getProperty` method. And this is because as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416312/369946), `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is only valid during bean creation.