# How to load and iterate through properties file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, properties-file

I've a `properties` file in which the values are comma separated. I'm able to get the values as `Object` as below. Could anyone please tell me how to separate the values and get it in String.

**.properties**

```
key-1 = value1,value11
key-2 = value2,value22
key-3 = value3,value33
key-4 = value4,value44
```

**Code**

```
@PropertySource( value = "classpath:test1.properties", name = "test1" )

AbstractEnvironment ae = (AbstractEnvironment)env;
org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource test1Source = 
ae.getPropertySources().get("test1");
Properties propsTest1 = (Properties)test1Source.getSource();

   for(Object key : propsTest1.keySet()){
   System.out.println("Properties file======>   propsTest1.get(key));
  }
```

Comment: Spring Expression Language ([SPEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)) will help your case. Check this question for some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value

Comment: please share your expected output as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below.

```
Properties propsTest1 = (Properties)test1Source.getSource();

for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> e : propsTest1.entrySet()){

   String value = (String)e.getValue();
   String[] values = value.split(",");
   // If you have spaces as between values, you have to take care of it.
}
```

Comment: I like @Darshan Mehta's answer better.

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Value` annotation with `@PropertySource` to get the value of a property. Also, you can use Spring Expression to split it into list, e.g.:

```
@PropertySource( value = "classpath:test1.properties", name = "test1" )
public class PropertyClass {

    @Value("#{'${key-1}'.split(',')}") 
    private List<String> key1Values;
}
```

This would give you the list of all the values configured against `key-1`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the values dynamically than creating a variable for every key?

Comment: Don't think there is any way to do this unless you subclass `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, read here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416312/1120793

Comment: This answer is good. But, I accepted Vinay's answer because it solved my problem. Upvoted your answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**.properties**

```
map.key[0] = value1,value11
map.key[1] = value2,value22
map.key[2] = value3,value33
map.key[3] = value4,value44
```

**Code**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="map")
public class YourConfig {

    private List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getKeys() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```

Or you can use:

```
keys={key-1:'value1',key-1:'value2',....}
```

**Code**

```
@Value("#{${keys}}")  private Map<String,String> keys;
```